# Можно ли прикрутить кусок кода на Java к PHP?

Tags: php, java

Есть расчетные модули написанные на Java под Android.

Собираюсь освоить PHP для разработки серверной части и хочу использовать эти расчетные модули на сервере. 
Можно ли это сделать, чтобы не переписывать код на PHP?

Comment: смотря что у Вас в настоящий момент реализовано

Comment: не очень понял коммент. Есть множество классов, библиотека .jar, все это протестировано в андроид приложении. Теперь надо чтобы то же самое было на сервере и генерились html страницы с результатами расчетов.

Comment: Так не проще ли просто на java всё реализовать? Ну либо, как написали в ответе, оформить это как микросервис, т.е. расчетная часть на java, а php сервер будет получать данные с интерфейса, отдавать их java приложению, которое всё посчитает и вернет в php.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то для реализации на java в виде микросервиса нужно чтобы хостинг поддерживал Java. Не будет ли с этим проблем? php это уже само собой разумеющееся на любом хостинге. А java? Спрашиваю, потому что вообще не имел с этим дела.

Comment: Покупайте VPS или выделенный хостинг и ставьте туда что угодно, любые программы и делайте с ними что захотите. А вот с шаред хостингами, облаками и клауд серверами могут возникнуть проблемы ну я думаю вам это не понадобится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно подружить их с помощью томката, читать **[тут](http://nikita-petrov.com/articles/o-tom-kak-podruzhit-java-i-php)** но тут нужно понимать что это довольно геморно подрубать не нужные по сути либы что бы выполнить и передать данные из java в php

Возможно проще сделать 2 отельных микросервиса и обмениваться информацией между ними.